# Inserting new Widgets as List on Pressing Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget, contacts

I am making a screen like this which could select contacts from the phone book and insert the names as lists in my application. I want is that when I press Add caregiver(+) button it should select a contact and show the name.
I made a Widget for the MOM part but whenever I click the button it rewrites the MOM to any contact that I select from the phone book.

I made this screen:

[image]

I also want to add Dad and Sister's Contact in the same manner as mom, but I am unable to do it

[image]

This is my code for the screen:

```
import 'package:epicare/NavigBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_switch/flutter_switch.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:contact_picker/contact_picker.dart';

//Check contacts permission
Future<PermissionStatus> _getPermission() async {

  final PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
      permission != PermissionStatus.denied) {
    final Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus =
    await [Permission.contacts].request();
    return permissionStatus[Permission.contacts] ??
        PermissionStatus.undetermined;
  } else {
    return permission;
  }
}


class CaregiverScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CaregiverScreenState createState() => _CaregiverScreenState();
}

class _CaregiverScreenState extends State<CaregiverScreen> {
  final ContactPicker _contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
  Contact _contact;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool isSwitched = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Add Caregiver",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return Homepage();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 40),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () async {

                      final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission();
                      if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                        //We can now access our contacts here
                        // var contactNumber = openContactBook();
                        Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
                        setState(() {
                          _contact = contact;
                        });
                      }
                      else {
                        //If permissions have been denied show standard cupertino alert dialog
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                              title: Text('Permissions error'),
                              content: Text('Please enable contacts access '
                                  'permission in system settings'),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                CupertinoDialogAction(
                                  child: Text('OK'),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                )
                              ],
                            ));
                      }
                    },
                    color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Add a Caregiver',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        height: 1.5384615384615385,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    textHeightBehavior:
                        TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  )
                ],
              ),
                _contact == null ? Container() : CaregiversList(_contact.fullName),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
Widget CaregiversList(String name){
    print(name);
    var c = name.split(' ');
    print(c[0]);
    var caregiver = c[0];
    var output = getInitials(string: caregiver, limitTo: 1);
    print(output);
    // var i = caregiver.codeUnitAt(0);
    // print(i);
    return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 27),
    child: Row(
      //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 24,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 22,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
              output,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: const Color(0xff000000),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 19),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              caregiver,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  height: 1.5384615384615385,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              textHeightBehavior: TextHeightBehavior(
                  applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
            isSwitched
                ? Text(
                    "Activated",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 10,
                        color: const Color(0x80232425),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  )
                : Text(
                    "Disabled",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 10,
                        color: const Color(0x80232425),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 143),
        FlutterSwitch(
          width: 40.0,
          height: 20.0,
          value: isSwitched,
          toggleSize: 15,
          borderRadius: 40.0,
          padding: 2.0,
          showOnOff: false,
          activeColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
          activeToggleColor: Colors.white,
          inactiveColor: const Color(0xffDDDBAF),
          inactiveToggleColor: Colors.white,
          onToggle: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isSwitched = value;
              print(isSwitched);
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

}
  String getInitials({String string, int limitTo}) {
    var buffer = StringBuffer();
    var split = string.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < (limitTo ?? split.length); i ++) {
      buffer.write(split[i][0]);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
  }
}
```

Please help me out as i am new to Flutter.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage Caregiverlist you've selected from contacts. for example

```
class Caregiver {
  String name;
  bool isActive;
  
  Caregiver({this.name, this.isActive});
  
  factory Caregiver.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
    return Caregiver(name: map['name'] ?? "", 
                     isActive: map['isActive']);
  }
}
```

- initialize caregiver list

  ```
  List<Caregiver> _careList = [];
  ```
- add Caregiver

  ```
  Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
  setState(() {
    _careList.add(Caregiver(name: contact, isActive: true));
  });
  ```
- show Caregiver list (To show ListView inside of Scrollview, add the following 3 lines.

  ```
  ListView.separated(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   primary: false,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {        
    return _caregiverWidget(index);
  },
  separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
  itemCount: _careList.length);
  ```
- Add new function

  ```
  Widget _caregiverWidget(int index) {
    Caregiver _caregiver = _careList[index];
    print(_caregiver.name);
    var c = _caregiver.name.split(' ');
    print(c[0]);
    var caregiver = c[0];
    var output = getInitials(string: caregiver, limitTo: 1);
    print(output);
    // var i = caregiver.codeUnitAt(0);
    // print(i);
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 27),
      child: Row(
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 24,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 22,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                output,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 19),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                caregiver,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    height: 1.5384615384615385,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
              _caregiver.isActive
                  ? Text(
                      "Activated",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: const Color(0x80232425),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    )
                  : Text(
                      "Disabled",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: const Color(0x80232425),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 143),
          FlutterSwitch(
            width: 40.0,
            height: 20.0,
            value: _caregiver.isActive,
            toggleSize: 15,
            borderRadius: 40.0,
            padding: 2.0,
            showOnOff: false,
            activeColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
            activeToggleColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: const Color(0xffDDDBAF),
            inactiveToggleColor: Colors.white,
            onToggle: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _caregiver.isActive = value;
                _careList.removeAt(index);
                _careList.insert(index, _caregiver);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: Where should I add the last two pieces of code? I made a new clas like you asked as well as i have updated the Contact picking line but for the last parts i.e 
show Caregiver list and toggle Activate/Deactivate, where should i use them?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/pra4w5zP
I added the codes you asked for, but it's giving me errors which I cannot figure out why, could you please look at my code on the link and help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: updated source code, but I couldn't test. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly right, Thank you so very much :)
You helped me with this code
I wanna ask one thing more if want to remove the Divider between the widgets then what should be used instead?

Comment: You are welcome. you can use Container(). Please replace Divider() to Container().

Comment: Yes i did the same, Thank you so much :)